# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot get printing to either Canon LBP3300 or Canon MG5460

Tags: 14.04, printing, canon

Newbie here.

Both my Canon LBP3300 and (wireless) MG5460 printers work on my network form Windows.
I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a desktop, went to Canon and downloaded the Linux driver package (cndrvcups-common_2.80-1_i386.deb) and installed it. The MG5460 was "seen" as a netwrok printer so I added it and it looked successful. When I tried to print a test page, the printer display showed that it was receiving data but then nothing. Ubuntu displayed "Idle - Waiting for job to complete.."

I have deleted the printer and re-installed several times with the same result.

If I could get printing to work I would seriously consider migrating to Ubuntu as it does everything else I need.

Cheers,
Stephen Hicks

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on this web site?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190?action=show&redirect=CanonCaptPrinterDriver#diagnostics:  Apparently the LPB3300 is Linux compatible but according to the chart it was last tested on 12.04.

Comment: I tried to do this but the download page for CUPs 2.4 is missing

Comment: If I try and install CUPs 2.4 do I have to uninstall CUPs 2.8 first? If so, how do I uninstall CUPS?

Comment: @user278815 - have you solved this problem? If so, you may want to add an answer explaining what you did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get my Canon LBP printer to run under Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463289/cant-get-my-canon-lbp-printer-to-run-under-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

Downloading and installing driver software for this printer from the Canon site resulted in an unmet dependency on `libtiff4` during the install. I found the key to get the MG5460 working wirelessly on 14.04 under [Dependency is not satisfiable: libtiff4 when trying to install Lightworks on Ubuntu 14.04](/a/449594).

So…

1. Manually install `libtiff4` for 14.04 as prescribed in the answer on that post.
2. Download the install for the printer from the Canon site. (At time of writing, this was titled *'MG5400 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.80 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)'*
3. Unzip and run the installation for the Canon driver.

   ```
   tar -xzf cnijfilter-mg5400series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz
   cd cnijfilter-mg5400series-3.80-1-deb
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```

   Provided all other dependencies are met, the installation also asks all the necessary questions to setup the printer over WiFi.

Immediately after installation, I was able to print.